# Keyframe Animation doesn't work in other browsers

Tags: css, animation, browser, keyframe

I am currently working with CSS3 keyframes. Sadly they only work in Chrome, even when I specify the other browsers in my keyframe. I don't know why it doesn't work and I would absolutely LOVE to get it solved. I have also been searching on StackOverflow, but I didn't find the answer for this question. Because I already specified the other browsers in my keyframe...

Please help?

```
df-messenger {
    --df-messenger-bot-message: #888;
    --df-messenger-button-titlebar-color: #f8c615;
    --df-messenger-chat-background-color: opacity 0.5;
    --df-messenger-font-color: #fff;
    --df-messenger-send-icon: #f8c615;
    --df-messenger-user-message: #555;
    -webkit-animation: changeColor 2s;
    -moz-animation: changeColor 2s;
    animation-name: changeColor;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: 3;
}



@-webkit-keyframes changeColor {
    from {
        --df-messenger-button-titlebar-color: #f8c615;
    }

    to {
        --df-messenger-button-titlebar-color: black;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes changeColor {
    from {
        --df-messenger-button-titlebar-color: #f8c615;
    }

    to {
        --df-messenger-button-titlebar-color: black;
    }
}

@-o-keyframes changeColor {
    from {
        --df-messenger-button-titlebar-color: #f8c615;
    }

    to {
        --df-messenger-button-titlebar-color: black;
    }
}

@keyframes changeColor {
    from {
        --df-messenger-button-titlebar-color: #f8c615;
    }

    to {
        --df-messenger-button-titlebar-color: black;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `dialogflow-es`?

Comment: The chatbot that I am using is made with Dialog Flow es..